# When should I use socket.pipe() on NodeJs net.socket

Tags: node.js

I have NodeJs handling incoming tcp connections from GPRS devices.

My question is, should I use socket.pipe(socket) at the scope of net.createServer(...) ?

Is calling this pipe() in this form that allow duplex communication, i.e. gprs->node and node->gprs? Or can I avoid calling this method?

Comment: First of all: you need 2 sockets for `.pipe()` to work. I'm not really sure where you have the second one? Secondly: `.pipe()` is **always** in one direction. Basically it reads the content from the readable stream and writes into the writable one.

Comment: I doesn't have much experience with node, so I followed the samples out there, that puts this command line [socket.pipe(socket)] and the end of net.createServer(). But I can't understand the impact of this call. It seems to me, through experimentation, that if I don't do that [socket.pipe(socket)], all the data that I try to write back to the gprs device, actually don't get its way to the output at all. The write back not work, i.e. [socket.write(...)]. I'm not saying that it throws any kind of error, only the the data is lost, like writing to a null device on linux fs.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't share your code, but generally speaking
`pipe()` is not necessary for achieving duplex communication
as tcp socket are by nature bi-directional.

```
net.createServer(function (gprsSocket) {
    gprsSocket.on('data', function (data) {
        // incoming data
        // every time the GPRS is writing data - this event is emited
    })

    // outgoing data
    // call this whenever you want to send data to
    // the GPRS regardless to incoming data
    gprsSocket.write('hello\n')
})
```

Answering your question - no, its not necessary.
In-fact calling `socket.pipe(socket)` will send all data received back to the GPRS.
and is basically doing something like this (though is not exactly the same)

```
gprsSocket.on('data', function (data) {
    // echo the data back to the gprs
    gprsSocket.write(data);
})
```

`pipe()` is used when you want to redirect one stream to another

```
// redirect all data to stdout
gprsSocket.pipe(process.stdout)
```